# How do I make multiple connections to a microcontroller's GND/VCC etc?

Tags: microcontroller, layout

If I'm hanging a number of switches and potentiometers and other sensors off a single microcontroller, I need to connect multiple wires to the µc's ground and VCC pins.

What's the best way to do that, physically? I can think of a couple of ideas (twist the wires together and hope they fit through the hole, crimp the wires together and hope they fit in the pin, make a little daughterboard out of [vero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veroboard)) but none of them feel neat or satisfying.

How do you pros do it?

Comment: Are you talking about a bare micro-controller chip, or a bout some module (Arduino, Raspberry Pi, etc)? Is this an experiment, or part of a more permanent construction?

Comment: Talking about an assembled microcontroller board like an Arduino, and the "more permanent" construction, once I've verified my circuit on a breadboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have verified your circuit on a solderless breadboard, a veroborad daugtherboard might indeed be a good next step. I prefer the veroboard that has sets of three holes connected. (others have entire rows connected, or copper rings about individual holes)

A dedicated PCB would of course be perfect, but it takes a lot of effort and/or one-time costs.

Answer (score 0):

(Not going to fit in a comment) Veroboard is what I use when I can. One of my last projects I had a PIC16F88 on breadboard with Vcc and Gnd rails. I kept it neat enough - with breadboard you have the rails on each side to connect to. I had several switches, leds, a usb to i2c converter and the PICKit3 hanging off it and it seemed ok(ish):

[image]

Note the little veroboard bits hanging off the side there. When I needed to demo it somewhere I transferred everything to veroboard and it can be very neat if you get some paper and design it first!

Having said that I needed 4 LEDs in fixed positions with a little surface mount connector (gnd and 4 IOs from a microcontroller). In that case (I wish I had a camera) I got a small piece of single sided blank PCB, about 2cm x 2cm, drilled the holes for the LEDs, joined them up with a Sharpie marker and chucked it in the etchant. Hey presto, a PCB without the pain!

For the Arduino I have just run out of GND and Vcc pins to poke wires into so I'll have to branch some of them (at one point, the power point, is the preferred strategy). I'm not beyond taking scrap veroboard and making things with it, including with surface mount components.

I would do something like this if I was so inclined:

[image: Arduino + Veroboard]